# Cannot dynamically load JavaScript file twice in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have build [this](http://www.s-maof.com/Forum/shorts.php) page. 
when you click on a row in the table, the page send an ajax request for data and then dynamically creates a script in the body called 
which loads the graph. It works in all chrome and FF but not in IE8. 
meaning -when you click on on row it work's but the second row and on the script are not loading..
I don't even know how to debug it in IE8. 
can someone recommend a solution?  :-)

the script that loads the other scripts is

```
$.post("shorts.server.php", $.param({
     val: stocknumber,
     id: id,
     name: stockname,
     group: stockgroup
 }), function (response) {
     //alert(response);
     // We dynamically add javascript headers
     var head = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
     script = document.createElement('script');
     //dynamic_graph.js changes it's content by the current selected stock
     //see shorts.server.php for details
     script.src = 'jQuery/head/dynamic_graph.js';
     head.appendChild(script);
     script = document.createElement('script');
     //dynamic_graph.js changes it's content by the current selected stock
     //see shorts.server.php for details
     script.src = 'jQuery/head/dynamic_info.js';
     head.appendChild(script);
 });
```

Comment: How can we not love the title? **It just says it all!** _"javascript jquery"_ perfect! wait, what about _"javascript jquery question"_ ?

Comment: @gdoron not any more :-)

Comment: @ManseUK. You ruined one of my best comment... :)

Comment: Aren't you supposed to have 'var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];' instead of 'var head = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];'?? That might solved the issue, althought I'm not sure about this one...

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
function(response)
{
     $.getScript('jQuery/head/dynamic_graph.js');
     $.getScript('jQuery/head/dynamic_info.js');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE9 press F12 to run the debugger. In the debugger you can select the browser mode like : IE8.
Use Jquery for all your DOM interactions and browser compatibility.